# A function with async is returning a fulfilled promise, how to access the data within

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

So, basically, I use React, and everything that is related to MERN stack. I am just learning so I'd like to learn the most I can.
I've encountered a problem, I am trying to fetch todos from a database and I use useState hook to get it done. I know that useState is on its own a promise, that works asynchronously but I don't know how to solve it.

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState(async () => {
        const dataToSet = await axios.get(`/${window.localStorage.getItem('userId')}`)
        console.log(dataToSet.data)
        return dataToSet.data
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(todos)
    }, [todos])
```

[Here's what I am getting in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIztW.png)

So, as you see. I return the dataToSet.data that is correct in the console. Finally, what I get back is the promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're setting the state to a `Promise`:

```
useState(async () => { /*...*/ });
```

Set the state to a *value*.  For example, if `todos` is an array, make it by default an empty array:

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
```

Then update state in your asynchronous operation.  Assuming that operation is meant to execute only once when the component first loads, put it in a `useEffect` with an empty dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getData = async () => {
    const dataToSet = await axios.get(`/${window.localStorage.getItem('userId')}`)
    console.log(dataToSet.data);
    setTodos(dataToSet.data);
  };
  getData();
}, []);
```

The call to `setTodos(dataToSet.data)` will update state, which will trigger the component to re-render with the new state.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have tried this with useEffect and async function inside it but I completely forgot to run the function that I've created.